# An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ',' in ssrs 2008 r2

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I am getting the error message, "An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ',' "
when running an ssrs 2008 r2 report.
The sql embedded in the dataset is:

```
IF @reportID <> 0
BEGIN
    SELECT 'Students report 1' AS selectRptName, 1 AS rptNumValue 
    UNION
    SELECT 'Students report 2', 2  
    UNION
    SELECT 'Students report 3', 3 
    UNION
    SELECT 'Students report 4', 4 
    UNION
    SELECT 'Students report 5', 5 
    ORDER BY selectRptName
END
```

The sql runs fine in managment studio when I declare `@reportID`.

The sql runs fine with I comment out  `'IF @reportID <> 0'`.

The `@reportID` is a parameter value that is passed to the applicable dataset. 
The `@reportID` can have more than one value.

Thus can you show me sql and/or tell me what I need to do to solve the issue for me?

Comment: what do you mean by `@reportID` can have more than one value? do you mean its a Multiple-value parameter ? Also you cannot use `IF..ELSE` statements inside your SSRS query builder.

Comment: The @reportID can have 0, 1 or 200 values. I am thinking of calling a function that splits out parameter values. How would I setup the sql?

Comment: @M.Ali SQL has an `IF` conditional and it works fine in SSRS datasets. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms182717.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In order to check the value of a multi-value parameter you need to use the `IN` operator.

```
IF 0 NOT IN (@reportID)
```

But it sounds to me like you're trying to check how many values have been assigned to the multi-value parameter and you can't really do that directly in the SQL query.

In your dataset properties go to the Parameters section and add a new parameter that's value is set by an expression. Then use this expression to set that parameter to the number of items in the multi-value parameter:

```
=Parameters!reportID.Count
```

You can then use that parameter in your SQL to check the number of values assigned to the multi-value parameter.

For more information about the Parameters collection in SSRS see this MSDN page: [Parameters Collection References (Report Builder and SSRS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255264.aspx)

Comment: changed the code to the following:IF 0 not in (@reportID)